# автоматически генерируемые страницы wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно удалить или скрыть от публичного просмотра автоматически генерируемые страницы вордпрессом для тегов (теги записей) и авторов, категорий. Когда нажимаю редактировать страницу, она никуда не приводит, лишь поменять название категории или тегу. Не знаю, как выявить эти страницы, чтоб скрыть

Answer (score 0):

Вообще ответ на Ваш вопрос довольно легко [гуглится](https://wpschool.ru/kak-ubrat-arhivy-wordpress/). Если не использовать плагины, то в файл functions.php нужно добавить следующий код:

```
add_action( 'parse_query', function ( $query ) {
    if( is_category() || is_tag() || is_author() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
});
```

Тогда при попытке перейти к категориям, тегам или авторам пользователь будет автоматически перенаправлен на главную страницу сайта.